# Problem compiling libpqxx 7.0.5, can't find postgreSQL libraries

Tags: c++, postgresql, sh, archlinux, libpqxx

I'm trying to compile [libpqxx 7.0.5](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/releases/tag/7.0.5) and It's having problems finding the postgresql libraries, which I have installed.

I have installed both [postgresql](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=postgresql) and [postgresql-libs](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=postgresql-libs). Why is giving me this error?.

The [configure](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/blob/master/configure) script stops at this:

```
configure: using PostgreSQL headers at
configure: using PostgreSQL libraries at
checking /libpq-fe.h usability... no
checking /libpq-fe.h presence... no
checking for /libpq-fe.h... no
configure: error:
Can't find libpq-fe.h in .  Are you sure the libpq
headers are installed correctly?  They should be in the directory returned by
"pg_config --includedir" or "pkg-config libpq --cflags".

If you do have libpq (the C-language client library for PostgreSQL) installed,
make sure you have the related development materials--mainly its header files--
as well as the library binary.  Some system distributions keep the two in
seperate packages with names like "alibrary" and "alibrary-dev", respectively.
In that case, make sure you have the latter installed as well.
```

The file is indeed inside my `/usr/include` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get this working. I needed to add the directory to where the libraries are.

```
./configure --with-postgres-include='/usr/include'
```

Doing this everything works!.

Also I downgrade libpqxx to version [7.0.3](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/releases/tag/7.0.3).